# PHP: Telegram Bot: Insert line break to text message

Tags: php, telegram-bot, linefeed

`"\n"` and `"\r\n"`, tested in text message sent by telegram bot, to create line break. Instead of showing line break, underline `_` will appear after using them.

How I could printing line feed in telegram message sent by bot?

***CODE***

```
$txt = 'با تشکر از عضویت شما، هر روز حدود ساعت 10 شب یک ویدئوی جالب برای شما ارسال خواهد شد.';
$txt .= " \n ";
$txt .= 'Thanks for joining, Every day at almost 18:30 GMT an intersting video will be sent';
```

**Message Demo**
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Dagon thanks a lot, first one just duplicate the message and print it twice, but second one do the job. Can I ask where is the source of these codes?

Comment: first google hit for me was: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-in-my-sms-message

Comment: a simple `\n` should work, its possible that the bot manager that you are using is doing some kine of clean up before sending the message.
I am using nodejs and `\n` works just fine.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

There is a better way! The problem is because of URL encodings...
You can use normal PHP text using `\n` but by passing it to `urlencode` method, as follows:

```
$txt = urlencode("here is my text.\n and this is a new line \n another new line");
```

It works for me!

Comment: Sorry Majid, Now I test another answer and all options failed, So I uncheck his answer and check yours

Comment: urlencode does not work for me (it encodes everything, including spaces). If you in a habit like me to use single quotes, \n must be in double quotes: $text = ' my text' . "\n";

Answer (score 53):

1) If you develop your code in Windows/Linux OS, you can simply use enter in text:

```
$text = 'test 123
         another text';
```

Thats all!

2) If your code run on Windows/Linux server, you can use `PHP_EOL` constant instead of `\n`:

```
$text = 'text 123 '.PHP_EOL.'yet another text';
```

3) And if you search for an OS independent soloution, you can use `%0A` or `chr(10)` for this purpose:

```
$text = 'text 123 '.chr(10).'yet another text';
```

Comment: @Majid because you are on Mac!
in iOS, the `PHP_EOL` and line break, is equal to `%0D` (or `\r`). but in linux and windows, the `PHP_EOL` and line break is equal to `%0A` (or `\n`) AND `%0D%0A` (or `\r\n`).

Comment: @Majid i add third way for you :)

Comment: Thank you for considering the issue. I'm on Mac, but the server that runs the PHP codes is a linux server on the Internet! Anyway thank you for adding the third way :-)

Answer (score 37):

For future visitor just I quote @Dagon answer in comments:

Using `%0A` will make line feed in telegram messages

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The `urlencode` function is not language agnostic. Your solution works when using the telegram API in any environment or language.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `%0A` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 6):

After reading and trying all of these answers, I just wanted to post my own solution. I have an application in Laravel 5.8 that sends the reservation both by e-mail and a Telegram message.

```
$telegramMessage = 
        "<strong>Reservation Request</strong>\n".
         '<strong>Name:</strong> ' . $reservation->reserv_name . "\n".
         '<strong>E-mail:</strong> <a href="mailto:' . $reservation->email . '"> ' . $reservation->email . "</a>\n".
         '<strong>Phone:</strong> ' . $reservation->phone . "\n".
         '<strong>Reservation Date/Time:</strong> ' . $reservation->reserv_date_time->format('d-m-Y H:i') . "\n".
         '<strong>Number of people:</strong> ' . $reservation->number_of_people . "\n".
         '<strong>Message:</strong> ' . $reservation->reserv_message . "\n";

Telegram::sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => env('TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID', ''),
            'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
            'text' => $telegramMessage,
        ]);
```

More or less I have used all the html tags that Telegram API allows. You should pay attention \n must be in double quotes.

Comment: Double quotes was the solution for me

Answer (score 4):

To avoid coding and encoding issues, I used this simple solution in my code:

- **First**, I send my text message in HTML format by setting the *parse_mode=HTML* argument in the "sendMessage" URL.
- **Then**, I insert the following code for each line break:

  `<pre>\n</pre>`

ie.

```
... sendMessage?parse_mode=HTML&text="... paragraph1<pre>\n</pre>paragraph2 ..."
```

Of course the **text** variable was curl escaped before appended to the URL:

```
$text = curl_escape($handle, $text);
```

Answer (score 3):

it may be not show result as you wants in Unicode languages like Persian!
you can prepare your text and use this:

```
$txt = implode("\n", explode('\n', $txt));
```

Answer (score 2):

ez way

```
$txt = "Thanks for joining, Every day at </br> almost 18:30 GMT an intersting video will be sent";
```

or

```
$txt = "Thanks for joining, Every day \r\n at almost 18:30 GMT an intersting video will be sent";
```

Answer (score 1):

for me this solution works:
use double quotation mark

```
$message='Hi'
$message=$message."\n";
$message=$message.'Guys'
```

Answer (score 1):

All these answers are at the same time "right" and "wrong". In fact in depend a lot of the input you have. For example if you have a text area for input and then send the content to Telegram, if the user write in the text area and press return, the text in Telegram will be

```
       hello\neverybody
```

and not

```
       hello
       everybody
```

Performing URL encode will change nothing. After struggling a lot I discover a conflict with the fact sending the text area data from a page to another page escape some data.

The way I solve that is to remplace the escaped \n by a non-escaped one.
So:

```
      $my_msg = str_replace("\\n","\n",$my_msg);
```

It works on Mac, PC and so on with text from text area.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way :

```
$txt = 'aaaaaaaaa\nnew line1 \nnewline2';
$parameters = array('chat_id' => $chatId, "text" => $txt);

$parameters["method"] = "sendMessage";
echo json_encode($parameters);
```

try here : https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs/sendmessage

Answer (score 0):

you should use urlencode to solve this problem:

```
$text ="sth sth
sth sth";
$text = urlencode($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, its work for me, and you need to add parameter parse_mode.

```
$text = "exampletest \n example"
```

or someting like this:

```
$text1 = 'example';
$text2 = 'next';
$data = $text1 . "\n" . $text2;
```

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options

Answer (score -1):

It it easy just copy break line from anywhare to pass in code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdfvh.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.