# Telegram REST API, send newline in message text?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send an message via the Telegram API in a `<pre>` block or ```` ``` ```` (HTML or markdown parse mode, I have no preference).

The text is a long string with some line breaks. To make it easy to read I want to send it as code. The new lines are in the `\n` format, so the Telegram API can handle that.

But in the code block I can't see the newlines. I've used other bots that can send me some lines in a code block, so I'm reasobaly sure it's possible.

Can somebody help me with this?

This is the code that I'm currently using:

````
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/$telegram_apikey/sendMessage?chat_id=$telegram_chatid&parse_mode=Markdown&text=```" . $message ."```";
        $telegramResult = file_get_contents($url
);
````

Where message is something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------- \n
------------ IMPORT RESULTS ---------------- \n
-------------------------------------------- \n
Product count: 12345 \n
Created: 1234 \n
Total time:  200 \n
-------------------------------------------- \n
```

Comment: Do you expect "\n" or newline?

Comment: I expect a newline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Telegram Bot: Insert line break to text message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908527/php-telegram-bot-insert-line-break-to-text-message)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I got it working.

Instead of sending `\n` to Telegram, you need to send `%0A`.

Comment: Woked! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Worked for me in python3 too, thanks alot.

Answer (score 4):

I see you've found a solution but you might be better off using [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode your `$message`.

This should convert your newlines to `%0A` as well as converting any other illegal or potentially dangerous characters like `&`, `#` or `?` if they appear in your message.

Answer (score 0):

@Azquilt is absolutely right, you must use `urlencode`

````
$telegram_apikey = 'API_KEY';
$telegram_chatid = 777;

$product_count = 12345;
$created = 1234;
$total_time = 200;

$message = <<<TEXT
--------------------------------------------
------------ IMPORT RESULTS ----------------
--------------------------------------------
Product count: $product_count
Created: $created
Total time:  $total_time
--------------------------------------------
TEXT;

$message = urlencode("```$message```");

$url = "https://api.telegram.org/$telegram_apikey/sendMessage?chat_id=$telegram_chatid&parse_mode=Markdown&text=$message";
$telegramResult = file_get_contents($url);
````

Answer (score 0):

`\n` works good if you send query data in the body of your `POST` request, not in query params

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).