# Adding <br> tag to php

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send notifications by Laravel, everything works fine but I have sort of style issue,

> How can I add `<br>` tag to this line of `php`?

```
public function toTelegram($product)
    {
     return TelegramMessage::create()
         ->to('@xxxxx')
         ->content('New Product is here ' .$product->title) //need br here
         ->button('Shop Now', 'http://domain.co/store/'. $product->slug);
    }
```

I want `$product->title` shows in a new line when the user receives the notification.

**PS: I tried `\n` , `\r\n` even `<br>` but nothing changed.**

this is how it looks like now:

[image: screen 1]

Comment: How did you add `\r`? Which quotes do you use?

Comment: Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908527/php-telegram-bot-insert-line-break-to-text-message)

Comment: @C2486 that works.. :) please share an answer i'll approve it

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line

```
content('New Product is here ' .$product->title)
```

by

```
content(nl2br("New Product is here  \n" .$product->title))
```

Comment: I'm not sure that telegram markup supports html `<br />`.

Comment: it's printing `\n` e.g `New Product is here   \nTITLE`

Comment: @u_mulder i think they support markdown

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this line,
 `->content('New Product is here ' .$product->title) //need br here`
 to this, 
`->content('New Product is here '.'<br>'.$product->title)`
try replacing the < br> with \n...

Answer (score 0):

```
->content('New Product is here '.PHP_EOL.$product->title);
```

I think PHP_EOL should work. It is php after all.

Also doing some research i think this one should also work:

```
->content("New Product is here  \n".$product->title); //double quotes
```